# CSS - Sticky Footer With Multiple Divs Inside Footer Not Working

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am trying to implement a sticky footer which has three divs stacked inside the footer div. Now if I load a page where I keep the content block empty, the footer is not sticky anymore :(. I was wondering what am I doing wrong?

CSS (Code Stripped to show only the relevant CSS):

```
/* Custom Sticky Footer */
 .wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -553px; /* Should be -553 px, but somehow doesnot work. This is a hack */
}
.push,
.footer {
    height: 553px;
}

.footer{
    background-color: #fff;
}

#footer-margin-top{
    height: 20px;
}
#footer-top{
    background-color: #333333;
    height:402px;
}
#footer-bottom{
    background-color: #232323;
    height: 131px;
    border-top: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

And HTML (Code Stripped to show only the relevant divs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>


    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div id="footer-margin-top"></div>
        <div id="footer-top">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 social">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wgx9/)

Comment: are you not using jquery? are you wanting the footer menu to pop up on button click? or do you always want the footer the same height? if always the same height, just use position: fixed bottom: 0 for your footer

Comment: What is "the content block?"  I can't really see a problem in the jsfiddle, so I don't think I'm understanding

Comment: are you trying to get the effect on http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html where the footer is either below the content if it fills the screen, or at the bottom of the page if it does not ?

Comment: The solution from anonymousxxx fixed my problem. Thanks everyone for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
html, body { height : 100% }
```

see on [cssdesk](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/lmtpedoi) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/AyQ8Z/show/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly with what you mean with sticky footer, then I suggest you to use this code :

.footer{
    background-color: #fff;
    **position:fixed;**
    **bottom:0;**     //set sticky on the most bottom of your pages
}